# Printing a 2d array in sfml from a text file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

Im trying to print out a 2d array of characters that is from a text file, into a renderwindow using the window.draw() function. However, everything seems to work perfectly fine, except that when printing its skipping exactly one character.
For instance if i had a line of 15 chars, it will only print 8,but when i print it on the terminal it prints it perfectly fine, I simply dont know why its behaving like that, tried several things like changing the text file itself, or changing the size. Nothing seems to work for me. any ideas or help is very much appreciated.

here is the part of the code:

```
void Level::printgrid(int level)
{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Game On");
sf::Font MyFont;

if (!MyFont.loadFromFile("tnr.ttf"))
{
    // Error...
}

ifstream my_file("nn.txt"); //text that i will be reading from 
char number;   

int i = 0; //to help loop
int j = 0;

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
        else
        {
            window.clear();
            while (i<row) // ive tried 2 for loops that didnt work cause
            {             // it kept re-entering those loops 
                while (j<col)
                {
                    my_file.get(grid[i][j]); //getting the chars one by one
                    cout << grid[i][j];  // printing them on terminal 
                                         //so i can check its correct
                    //changing to text that is drawable to print in window  
                    sf::Text text(grid[i][j], MyFont, 30);
                    text.setPosition(0 + (30 * i), 0 + (30 * j));
                      // drawing it in window
                    window.draw(text);
                    window.display();
                    j++;
                }
                my_file.get(number);
                cout << endl;
                i++;
                j = 0;
            }
        }
    }

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code, but the most apparent problem is the fact that you're always drawing only one character, then presenting the result (which will flip buffers).

Due to this you're basically alternating characters between the two buffers (since SFML is double buffering).

In addition, you're continually reading from your file, recreating the characters/text elements, etc. which is not very effective and should fail once you reach the end of the file.

For some actual game or program, you should work on optimizing the drawing (drawing 10 characters at once as one `sf::Text` is faster than drawing 10 individual `sf::Text` objects). I'll be ignoring this for simplicity for now.

The following is just a quick (untested) example to show you the basic idea.

```
// First I'd use some container to store our `sf::Text` objects
// This will just create all the objects
std::vector<sf::Text> chars(rows * cols);

// Now let's read the characters and add to our vector
for (std::size_t y = 0; y < rows; ++y) {
    for (std::size_t x = 0; x < cols; ++x) {
        // Just an alias to simplify the following lines
        sf::Text &text = chars[y * cols + x];

        // Now just set up everything
        text.setFont(my_font);
        text.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
        text.setCharacterSize(30);
        text.setPosition(30 * x, 30 * y);
        text.setString(my_file.get());
    }
}

while (window.isOpen()) {
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        // Just your usual event handling
    }

    window.clear();
    // Iterate over all elements and draw them
    for (const auto &text : chars)
        window.draw(text);
    window.display();
}
```

If you're trying to create some kind of graphical console, you should put all characters into some `sf::VertexArray` or potentially render them using a shader.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I have realized that you were right that SFML is double buffering. I have tried to draw my 2D array line by line and still wont work. I have also tried your suggestion but the text.string function is not working. I have even tried sf::VertexArray but couldnt get that to work. Been stuck at this for hours and cant get my app to start. Is there a different approach to print out from a given text file? Thank you.

Comment: @Newdragon Define "not working". Also try a more simple approach, render static and hard coded text, then replace it. Also try debugging/stepping through your code to ensure variables got the right contents.